# Play animation wait 2 seconds and repeat

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm using `UIView.animate` to animate a simple UIView.
Starting conditions: `width = height = 30, color = blue` (I set this in the Storyboard)

I want to increase the size to w=50, h=50 and make it white, while it has an appropriate cornerRadius. Then I reset the view and do the same animation again.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var swipeRightView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doubleTab: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for _ in 0...2 {
            startAnimation()
            sleep(5)
            self.doubleTab.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            startAnimation()
        }
    }

    func startAnimation() {
        self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.doubleTab.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.doubleTab.frame.size.width += 20
            self.doubleTab.frame.size.height += 20
            self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = self.doubleTab.frame.size.width / 2
        }) { (_) in
            self.doubleTab.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.34, green: 0.61, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1)
            self.doubleTab.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
            self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = self.doubleTab.frame.size.width / 2

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
                self.doubleTab.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                self.doubleTab.frame.size.width += 20
                self.doubleTab.frame.size.height += 20
                self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = self.doubleTab.frame.size.width / 2
            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but i want to repeat the whole animation. When the whole animation is finished I want to wait 2 seconds and then repeat it, then wait 2 seconds and repeat and so on. As you can see in `viewDidLoad` I tried to repeat the animation with a `for-loop` but this has no affect or a wrong behavior. A `repeat - while` has also no effect. So, how can i repeat this animation? 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could call the `startAnimation` function *recursively*, which means call it again after it's completed, which will call itself again after it completed and so on.

So you could basically add `, completion: { _ in self.startAnimation() }` in the last block where you've currently set `completion: nil`.
If you wanted to add a delay, you could add the delay in the function as parameter and make it `0` by default for the first animation cycle.

The full code would then be:

```
func startAnimation(delay: TimeInterval = 0) {
    self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: delay, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
        self.doubleTab.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.doubleTab.frame.size.width += 20
        self.doubleTab.frame.size.height += 20
        self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = self.doubleTab.frame.size.width / 2
    }) { (_) in
        self.doubleTab.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.34, green: 0.61, blue: 0.88, alpha: 1)
        self.doubleTab.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = self.doubleTab.frame.size.width / 2

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear], animations: {
            self.doubleTab.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.doubleTab.frame.size.width += 20
            self.doubleTab.frame.size.height += 20
            self.doubleTab.layer.cornerRadius = self.doubleTab.frame.size.width / 2
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.startAnimation(delay: 2)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: inside the completion you should reset every Thing that changed or it will be useless to repeat old things

Comment: @LinusGeffarth: Thank you, but this will not repeat the whole animation. The whole animation represents a double tab. But when the animation begins to repeat it represents a single tab. So it seems that only one animation is repeating. But you gave me the right starting point.

Comment: @matt, this was not rudeness but a genuine question.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth In my opinion I'm saving you from yourself. I've been guilty of the same sort of thing, and I've paid for it. My tiny deletion vastly improves the whole tone and appearance of the question, I think. But if you want to rollback, be my guest. I won't get into a ko fight with you.

Comment: If I hadn’t understood your point and reasoning, I would have rolled back already. So thanks, I guess :)